# Limit Number of elements in a string aggregation query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, group-by, string-aggregation

I have below table and string aggregation using XML:

```
            CREATE TABLE TestTable ([ID] INT, [Name] CHAR(1))


            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (1,'A')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (2,'B')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (3,'C')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (1,'D')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (1,'E')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (2,'F')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (3,'G')
            INSERT INTO TestTable ([ID],[Name]) VALUES (4,'H')

            SELECT 
              [ID],
              STUFF((
                SELECT '   ' + [Name] 
                FROM TestTable 
                WHERE (ID = Results.ID) 
                FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')
              ,1,2,'') AS Names
            FROM TestTable Results
            GROUP BY ID
```

I get below result

```
        ID  Names
        1    A   D   E
        2    B   F
        3    C   G
        4    H
```

However i have requirement to limit number of Names to two, if its more than two, it should split to next row, Something like below. Here for ID=1, there were 3 Names, so 3rd name split into next row. How can i achieve this requirement

```
    ID  Names
    1    A   D
    1    E
    2    B   F
    3    C   G
    4    H
```

Thanks

Comment: `STUFF` does nothing but remove a trailinig separator. What you're doing is aggregating strings using XML. If you use SQL Server 2017+, use `STRING_AGG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want conditional aggregation, with up to two `name` columns per row.  You can do this using `row_number()` and some arithmetic:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then name end) as name1,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then name end) as name2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by name) as seqnum
      from testtable t
     ) t
group by id, ceiling(seqnum / 2.0)
order by id, min(seqnum);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c3cf19b6f5235462c23f8b2438affb9b) is a db<>fiddle.

I should note that you can concatenate these into a single column.  I don't see a reason to do so, because you know the maximum number on each row.

Comment: @Bhimrathor The point with this is you don't need to use `FOR XML PATH` as you know exactly how many you want

Comment: Thanks You. I was able to meet my requirement with this.